# Change DatePicker Text Color

Tags: android, datepicker, android-styles

I want to change the text color of `DatePicker`.

I have tried couple of suggestions found here but nothing has worked for me.
The text color, and the selected background stays the same.

The top header background did changed.

```
<style name="MyThemeDesign" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/btnColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
        <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/orange</item>
        <item name="android:text">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:calendarTextColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:dayOfWeekBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:selectedWeekBackgroundColor">@color/colorRed</item>
        <item name="android:yearListSelectorColor">@color/colorRed</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@color/colorRed</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerMode">calendar</item>
        <item name="android:minDate">01/01/2017</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  ...
  <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.DatePicker">
  <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/red</item>
  <item name="android:headerMonthTextAppearance">@style/MyDatePickerTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDatePickerTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1">
  <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/my_color_state_list</item>
</style>
```

**drawable/my_color_state_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!-- Month color -->
  <item android:color="@color/yellow" android:state_selected="true"/>
  <!-- Year color -->
  <item android:color="@color/purple" />
</selector>
```

If you also want to control the selected date color, then add this theme to `style.xml`:

```
<style name="MyDatePickerTheme" parent="AppTheme">
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

In layout:

```
<DatePicker
    android:theme="@style/MyDatePickerTheme"
    .../>
```

Result:

[image]