# DatePicker headerTextColor: cannot resolve attribute

Tags: android, datepicker, android-resources, android-styles, android-attributes

I want to apply some style to `DatePicker`. In [platform's `attrs.xml`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml#L4798) we can see following attributes for `DatePicker` styleable:

```
<declare-styleable name="DatePicker">
    ...
    <!-- The text color for the selected date header text, ex. "2014" or
         "Tue, Mar 18". This should be a color state list where the
         activated state will be used when the year picker or day picker is
         active.-->
    <attr name="headerTextColor" format="color" />

    <!-- The background for the selected date header. -->
    <attr name="headerBackground" />
    ...
</declare-styleable>
```

While I can refer to `android:headerBackground`, unexpectedly I cannot do that for `android:headerTextColor` attribute. So following code in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.DatePicker">
  <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/red</item>
  <item name="android:headerTextColor">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

prompts with error, that `android:headerTextColor` cannot be resolved.

[image]

But I can [clearly see](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles_material.xml#L707) `Widget.Material.DatePicker` overriding that attribute. Interestingly that chunk of code is preceded with `Attributes for new-style DatePicker` comment, which may somehow lead to the cause of this behavior.

What maybe the cause of this behavior and how to override that attribute?

<sup>Running on Android Studio 2.3, minSdkVersion 23, buildToolsVersion 25.0.3,
 compileSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion 23, invalidated caches and cleaned project.</sup>

---

As you can see in [`R.attr` docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#headerDayOfMonthTextAppearance), there is this text behind some attributes:

> This constant was deprecated in API level 23. Use *headerTextColor* instead.

Which means, that this attribute should be exposed to public API, but somehow it is being stripped and AAPT cannot access it.

Opened [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62399525) at bug tracker.

Comment: <item name=app:headerBackground">@color/red</item>

Comment: Odd. I am seeing that same behavior. `android:headerMonthTextAppearance` stills works to override the appearance of the month. Unfortunately, `android:headerYearTextAppearance`  also seems to be broken, so this would be only half of a work-around.

Comment: @Cheticamp, I also saw that behavior concerning `android:headerYearTextAppearance`. I stumbled to this issue when answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44088524/1083957). Somehow, I could find seams to change year text appearance, but it was mystery for me why this attribute wasn't seen. It seems like a bug.

Answer (score 5):

[image: style attribute "android:attr/headerTextColor" is private]

AAPT says that the attribute is private. Probably they are missing a `@hide` in `attrs.xml`

Comment: Can you please clarify how exactly could you reproduce this error message? Are you using AAPT2? Secondly, I cannot see how this attribute should have been made `private` because they suggest using exactly this attribute instead of deprecated `headerMonthTextAppearance`, `headerDayOfMonthTextAppearance` and `headerYearTextAppearance`. See [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml#L4827).

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 3.0 to use AAPT2. 
You can also add `android.enableAapt2=false` to `gradle.properties` to use aapt2 in Android Studio 2.3.
yeah I see `headerTextColor` should not be private, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html is not documenting the attribute too.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while but since this hasn't been resolved yet, I worked around this by getting the header's view id and then setting the text color directly programmatically, after I call picker.show() in the fragment like this. Hopefully this will help someone that stumbles on this question.

```
int yearSpinnerId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("date_picker_header_year", "id", "android");
AppCompatTextView year = picker.findViewById(yearSpinnerId);
int headerTextId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("date_picker_header_date", "id", "android");
AppCompatTextView selectedDate = picker.findViewById(headerTextId);
year.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white_FFFFFF));
selectedDate.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white_FFFFFF));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this

Style.xml

```
 <style name="DatePicker">
        <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="headerTextColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
 </style>
```

Values folder
attr.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="DatePicker">
        ...
        <!-- The text color for the selected date header text, ex. "2014" or
             "Tue, Mar 18". This should be a color state list where the
             activated state will be used when the year picker or day picker is
             active.-->
        <attr name="headerTextColor" format="color" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: [`No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'headerTextColor'`](https://i.gyazo.com/290d94c771d9fc11518ea575b3260b9a.png)

Comment: Sorry **android:headerBackground** color we can set and it will take inverse color of it and set to **headerTextColor** which is private attr. Thanks Tin Tran

Comment: How do you know it is private? Secondly, I cannot see how it will take the inverse color of it. Assuming it takes, what if I do not want it to take that color?

Comment: <style name="TextAppearance.Material.DatePicker.YearLabel" parent="TextAppearance.Material">
        <item name="textColor">@color/primary_text_secondary_when_activated_material_inverse</item>
        <item name="textSize">@dimen/date_picker_year_label_size</item>
        <item name="fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
    </style>